# Bazel: How to extend existing docker image?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I know in Dockerfile I can extend existing docker image using:

```
FROM python/python
RUN pip install request
```

But how to extend it in bazel?

I am not sure if I should use `container_import`, but with that I am getting the following error:

```
container_import(
    name = "postgres",
    base_image_registry = "some.artifactory.com",
    base_image_repository = "/existing-image:v1.5.0",
    layers = [
        "//docker/new_layer",
    ],
)
```

```
root@ba5cc0a3f0b7:/tcx# bazel build pkg:postgres-instance --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug
ERROR: /tcx/docker/postgres-operator/BUILD.bazel:12:17: in container_import rule //docker/postgres-operator:postgres:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/2f47bbce04529f9da11bfed0fc51707c/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/import.bzl", line 98, column 35, in _container_import_impl
        "config": ctx.files.config[0],
Error: index out of range (index is 0, but sequence has 0 elements)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//pkg:postgres-instance' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//docker/postgres-operator:postgres' failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.209s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 2 targets configured)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container_import` is the correct rule to import an existing image. However, all it does is import, it doesn't pull it from anywhere. I think you're looking for [`container_pull`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#container_pull) instead, which will pull an image from a repository and then automatically use `container_import` to translate it for other rules_docker rules.

To add a new layer, use [`container_image`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#container_image), with `base` set to the imported image and `tars` set to the additional files you want to add. Or, if you want to add things in other formats, see the docs for alternates to `tars` (like `debs` or `files`).

Putting it all together, something like this in your `WORKSPACE`:

```py
container_pull(
  name = "postgres",
  registry = "some.artifactory.com",
  repository = "existing-image",
  tag = "v1.5.0",
)
```

and then this in a `BUILD` file:

```py
container_image(
  name = "postgres_plus",
  base = "@postgres//image",
  tars = ["//docker/new_layer"],
)
```

The specific problem you're running into is that `container_pull.layers` isn't for adding new layers, it's for specifying the layers of the image you're importing. You could import those some other way (`http_archive`, check in the tar files, etc) and then specify them all by hand instead of using `container_pull` if you're doing something unusual.